# JPA/Hibernate mapping error when entities are located in multiple JAR files

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange behaviour with JPA/hibernate.

I have 3 entities located in 2 JARs :

- JAR A

  - Order
  - OrderProduction
- JAR B

  - OrderProductionImpl

Order (from JAR A):

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parentOrder", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private OrderProduction production;
}
```

OrderProduction (from JAR A):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class OrderProduction implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="order_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable=false)
    private Order parentOrder;
}
```

OrderProductionImpl (from JAR B):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="production_order")
public class OrderProductionImpl extends OrderProduction implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDateTime;
}
```

This works perfectly with EclipseLink (Glassfish 3.0), but with Hibernate (JBoss 6), I get :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: testPU] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
```

But if a put all entities in the same JAR file, its OK with Hibernate.

I get the same result in unit testing or app server deployment.

How can I keep my entities in separate JAR files, while using hibernate ?

- [Edit] Precision: Other entities from JAR B are succesfully mapped.
- [Edit] Maybe a classloader problem with Hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate config file requires all the entities to be referenced relative to its path, so in my opinion you cannot have entities separated out in different jars.

Comment: problem resolved, and you can (fortunately) have entities separated out in different jars.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the jar-file tag in your persistence.xml configuration file?

According to the [JPA 2.0 Specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) 8.2.1.6.3

> One or more JAR files may be specified
>   using the jar-file elements instead
>   of, or in addition to the mapping
>   files specified in the mapping-file
>   elements. If specified, these JAR
>   files will be searched for managed
>   persistence classes, and any mapping
>   metadata annotations found on them
>   will be processed, or they will be
>   mapped using the mapping annotation
>   defaults defined by this
>   specification. Such JAR files are
>   specified relative to the directory or
>   jar file that contains[82] the root of
>   the persistence unit.[83]
>
> The following examples illustrate the
>   use of the jar-file element to
>   reference additional persistence
>   classes. These examples use the
>   convention that a jar file with a name
>   terminating in “PUnit” contains the
>   persistence.xml file and that a jar
>   file with a name terminating in
>   “Entities” contains additional
>   persistence classes.

```
app.ear
lib/earEntities.jar
earRootPUnit.jar (with META-INF/persistence.xml )

persistence.xml contains:
<jar-file>lib/earEntities.jar</jar-file>
```

You can see further examples in the spec.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I've been trying with the 'jar-file' tag or with the 'class' tag, same result. Precision: other entities from 'JAR B' are successfully mapped.

Comment: @jruillier Are you explicitly listing your entities in the persistence.xml file? Do you have the exclude-unlisted-classes tag set to true?

Comment: @jruillier Ok, Are the classes in your jar B (which you say are not being discovered by Hibernate) located in the list of entities in your persistence.xml file?

Comment: yes :). the problem was linked to a maven dependency misconfiguration. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you give further info on the maven misconfiguration please?